# Do minors flying from Portugal with only one parent need a parental consent letter?

Tags: uk, schengen, spain, minors, portugal

We are a Spanish family living in the UK. We are planning some holidays in Spain in which one of the parents would need to fly the children from Portugal back to the UK.

We know that, to leave the Schengen area, we need an authorisation from both legal guardians. To fly from Spain, we would need it validated at a Spanish police station (Guardia Civil). If we are traveling from Portugal, would we need a Portuguese document or will the Spanish one be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Portugal's Immigration and Borders Service (SEF)](http://www.sef.pt/portal/v10/EN/aspx/apoioCliente/detalheApoio.aspx?fromIndex=0&id_Linha=4350), it is not required when the child is travelling with one of his/her parents (added emphasis mine):

> **Minor, whose parents are married (to one another)**
>   The travel permit must be granted and signed by one of the parents, only if the child is travelling without either of them; in cases **where the child is travelling in the company of one parent, no permit is required**, provided there is no opposition by the other parent.